# Custom button to shift the calendar by one day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

According the documentation, the method "incrementDate" should move the calendar an arbitrary amount of time. (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-incrementDate)

This worked fine in my fullalendar 3 implementation, but in version 4, the behaviour is different:

In a week view, I have to click 7 times on the "+1day" button to switch the week. Actually, I would like to shift the calendar by one day on every click (tuesday to tuesday for example)
[See at my codepen](https://codepen.io/hrigu/pen/GRgwGMe)

```
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function() {
    calendar.incrementDate({ days: 1 });  
});
```

Any ideas?
Christian

Comment: You can try days: 7 to add 7 days so 1 week

Comment: But this is not what I want. Clicking the +1 day button should shift the week-view by, well, one day...